# Is there a way to access Windows APIs like CORTANA form electron / node.js apps?

Tags: node.js, electron, cortana

I just got the "Creators Update" on winodws 10.

I've read a while back that **Cortana** speech apis will become [available for developers trough an SDK](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/08/windows-developer-day-creators-update/) in this update.

Given that the node.js run-time is **not sandboxed** like the browser - is there a way to get the native **windows apis** like **Cortana** working in `node.js`? and by extension in `electron`.. using something like

`var cortana = require ('cortana');`

I couldn't find any `npm package` at this point. But i can't tell if is because it's too soon - or because there is some incompatibility here.

Can someone provide an explanation of what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are ways to make APIs like Cortana works with your app, for example botbuilder is an excellent npm package you can use:

> https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples